# Elastic Search + JSON import (ELK Stack)

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm currently trying to do a basic JSON file import into my ELK stack. I tried importing it directly via a POST request like this:

curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/kwd_results/TS_Cart -d @/home/local/TS_Cart.json

ES says ok for the import, but when I'm trying to view the logs in Kibanna, they are not indexed by the nodes of the JSON file. I'm guessing I need like a template mapping to view it properly.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "testResults": {
    "FitNesseVersion": "v20160618",
    "rootPath": "K1System.CountryDe.DriverFirefox.TestCases.MainFolder.TestVariants.SmokeTests_B2C.TS_Cart",
    "result": [
      {
        "counts": {
          "right": "16",
          "wrong": "2",
          "ignores": "3",
          "exceptions": "1"
        },
        "date": "2017-05-10T00:01:11+02:00",
        "runTimeInMillis": "117242",
        "relativePageName": "TestCase_1",
        "pageHistoryLink": "K1System.CountryDe.DriverFirefox.TestCases.MainFolder.TestVariants.SmokeTests_B2C.TS_Cart.B2CFreeCatalogueOrder?pageHistory&resultDate=20170510000111",
        "tags": "de, at"
      },
      {
        "counts": {
          "right": "16",
          "wrong": "0",
          "ignores": "0",
          "exceptions": "0"
        },
        "date": "2017-05-10T00:03:08+02:00",
        "runTimeInMillis": "85680",
        "relativePageName": "TestCase_2",
        "pageHistoryLink": "K1System.CountryDe.DriverFirefox.TestCases.MainFolder.TestVariants.SmokeTests_B2C.TS_Cart.B2CGiftCardOrderWithAdvancePayment?pageHistory&resultDate=20170510000308",
        "tags": "at, de"
      }
    ],
    "finalCounts": {
      "right": "4",
      "wrong": "1",
      "ignores": "0",
      "exceptions": "0"
    },
    "totalRunTimeInMillis": "482346"
  }
}
```

Basically I would need rootPath to be used as an index, while having the following childs: `counts, relativePageName, date and tags`. Notice that I have two nodes that are childs of the result[] array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's one JSON document so Elasticsearch treats it as such.

You'll need to (programmatically) split up the document into the right documents and then you can store them (potentially with one _bulk request).

For the index name:

1. Must be lowercase, so you'll need to cast that value.
2. Will you have many different root paths with jut a few docs each? Then you shouldn't make all of them an index since there is an overhead for each one of them (actually the underlying shards).